# Sorting a list of location by nearest first to my location - Android

Tags: java, android, sorting, location, comparator

```
private List<Location> sortLocations(List<Location> locations, final Location myLocation) {

        Comparator comp = new Comparator<Location>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Location o1, Location o2) {

                Float dist1 = o1.distanceTo(myLocation);
                Float dist2 = o2.distanceTo(myLocation);

                return dist1.compareTo(dist2);
            }
        };

        Collections.sort(locations, comp);

    return locations;
}
```

I want to sort a list of location by order of the nearest first to myLocation. Is my code correct, b'coz the problem is it's not sorting ascending or descending. Its just random even not similar to the database order.but the original and the new location list is same..  Plz help..

Comment: Can you please add your `Location` class

Comment: location is an android class. This is not the problem. But it would be useful if you test it yourself first maybe. If it is reversed then, just call Collections.reverse afterwards

Comment: "I think it's not working" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem (you're not even sure there *is* a problem!). Instead, describe the exact observed behavior and what the expected behavior should be. Include any example inputs, expected/actual outputs, and the exact text of any error messages, including the full [stack trace](//stackoverflow.com/a/23353174) of any exceptions, if applicable, as well as which line of code the stack trace points to. Please see [ask] and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](//stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: the problem is it's not sorting ascending or descending. Its just random even not similar to the database order.but the original and the new location list is same.

Answer (score 0):

**It may help**

```
 private List<Location> sortLocations(List<Location> locations, final Location myLocation) {
        Map<Float, Location> map = new TreeMap<>(Comparator.comparing(Float::floatValue));
        locations.forEach(location -> map.put(Math.abs(location.distanceTo(myLocation)), location));
        return new ArrayList<>(map.values());
    }
```